# php - How to store configuration in shared hosting

Tags: php, json, config, shared-hosting

Let's assume we have a shared host. The web root is located in `/home/username/www/`. Now, I have a PHP application which reads a configuration file, located at `/home/username/www/include/config.json`. This configuration file stores passwords and other configuration information. Assuming that access to `/home/username/` or any directory outside the web root is not possible, how would I go about securing `config.json` from people directly `GET`ting it?

If storing configuration information in a plaintext file is not feasible, please advise on other ways to do so.

Comment: Why can't you move it outside the webroot? That's the preferred option. I'd also suggest using a .htaccess block to that specific file.

Comment: You should create an API to access it. Something like `domain.com/config/get/`. Then, if you want to secure it you may add some query like token etc...

Comment: @Farkie You can't move it outside the web root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for secure your directory structure and prevent reading other files and content in your directory.

#### Disable directory content listing

**Using htaccess**
Putting the following the .htaccess file shall disable directory listing.

```
Options -Indexes
```

**Using index.html**
If the server does not allow this, then the easiest way is to put a dummy index.html file in all directories.
So that when directory path is accessed, the index.html will open up.

#### Keep resources outside WEB_ROOT

When hosting applications on a server , the path is generally like this :

```
/var/www/
```

OR

```
/home/username/www/
```

All web content is kept inside www , then only it is accessible on a website. But those contents which are not meant to be directly accessible from a url , can be kept outside the `/www`.

For example uploaded images , or resource files , or files containing database connection parameters or anything.

php files to be called by browser in

```
/var/www/
```

Other resource files in

```
/var/outside/
```

By doing this the files automatically become invisible to outside world even if directory listing is enabled.

Comment: `,htaccess` is the one! I forgot all about it. Thanks for this answer (I cannot move files outside web root)

Answer (score 0):

You need a .htaccess file in your include directory that will make it unavailable from outside:

```
Options -Indexes
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

or for apache 2.4

```
Options -Indexes
Require all denied
```

Another solution would be to move the include to /home/username/include